# add background color if action and save to database

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

I have a background color change applied to a `td` element when the `select` option is changed. What would be the simplest solution to keep the background color of that `td` on page refresh?

My first thought is to add a bit field to my sql table and key off its value on pageload, but I welcome other solutions.

Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selector').on('change', function(){
        if($('#selector').val() == 'on'){
          $('#immat').css({'background': 'lime'})
        }else{
          $('#immat').css({'background': 'white'}) 
        }             
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>GLEX</td>
        <td id="immat">MTEST</td>
        <td>ABC123</td>
        <td> <SELECT id="selector">
            <option selected disabled> </option>
            <option value="on">on board </option>
            <option value="off">not on board </option>
        </SELECT></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The easiest to keep it on page refresh would probably be to store it in session storage in the client and skip PHP entirely.

Comment: Per the previous comment, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: What it comes down to is the requirements. Is it only for the current user? Should it only be saved for during the current session or persistent between a users sessions?

Comment: It's not for one user. Other way to avoid php and sql? Whenna colo is changed everybody have to see it

Answer (score 0):

1/ If that data is stored and needed only on **front-end**, use JS `sessionStorage` or `document.cookie`.

2/ If that data is stored on the **server side**, use PHP `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE`.

3/ If that data is stored in the **database**, make a SQL request.

Comment: It is for multiple sessions

Comment: @Frenzye Reading your comments, you'll need to store the data on a database (multiple sessions, multiple users). In PHP, simply make your `UPDATE` and `SELECT` calls to your **SQL database** by using `mysqli_query()` (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.mysqli.php) or `PDO::query()` (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php)